# Appending data to xml file with DOM document

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to append new data to an existing xml file. This is what I have so far:

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->formatOutput = true;

 $doc->loadXml('library.xml');

 $path = new DOMXPath($doc);

 $b=$doc->createElement('book');

 $ISBN = $doc->createElement( 'isbn' );
 $ISBN->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode( $_GET['isbn'] )
  );
  $b->appendChild( $ISBN );


  $edition = $doc->createElement( 'edition' );
  $edition->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode( $_GET['ed'] )
      );
  $b->appendChild( $edition );*/


  $doc->save("library.xml");
```

I'm having trouble on how to get the place where I want to insert my data. I saw some use query() or this:

```
$query = sprintf('//record[./title[contains(., "%s")]]', $searchString);
```

but I'm wondering if someone can explain how the path is written.

Answer (score 0):

//record[./title[contains(., "%s")]]

is a xpath query it means find the record node in the xml with a title attribute that contains
 the searchstring

You need to get a reference to the node you want then appendChild to that. You appear to not append anywhere to a existing node

Have a look here at how to get where you want to append 
http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Comment: Thanks for your help, I know my code didn't have a reference node yet. The link that you gave me, I'm looking at this line:

 $query = //book/chapter/para/informaltable/tgroup/tbody/row/entry[. = "en"]';

I now understand that it's going from root to child nodes, but I'm a bit confused what "entry[.="en"]" means.

Comment: @user977151 the `entry[.="en"]` part of the xpath means looking for nodes named 'entry' with the content "en" : `<entry>en</entry>`